# Logback on windows doesn't close rotated logfiles

Tags: java, logback, filehandle, logrotate

My Java application uses Logback (version 1.1.3) with a RollingFileAppender and a FixedWindowRollingPolicy. The rollover is working as expected but on Windows I cannot delete the rotated files because Java keeps a lock on them.

I would expect the rotated files to be immediately released after the roll-over. Is this a bug in Logback or is there something I can do to force Logback to close the files immediately?

Comment: Have you confirmed that this behavior still exists with the latest logback (1.1.7)?

Comment: Just upgraded to 1.1.7 but the problem still exists.

Comment: Just checked the implementation of the FixedWindowRollingPolicy but in the end it just calls java.io.FileSystem.rename(). Maybe it's a more generic problem and not a Logback issue.

Comment: This exists at least as far as logback-classic 1.2.3. Just hit by this, causing massive CPU usage and disk thrashing (on Windows at least).